# Under what conditions is a question highlighted on questions page?

Tags: support

I'm looking at the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery page, there's a question tagged with `jquery html css` all of which are my favourite tags but it's not highlighted.

There's another question tagged `javascript jquery arrays ajax json`, which are not all in my favourite tags and it's highlighted.

1. How does the question highlighting work?
2. Is there a place to find answers to questions such as this one, some help page maybe which explains all these rules. I searched the questions here but couldn't find an answer.